# Convert rtf to pdf

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, pdf, itext, rtf

I Need to convert doc/docx to pdf with iTextSharp.dll. May i know how can i do that?

thanks

Comment: This has got to do with rtf why?

Comment: @m.edmondson: Not getting what you mean?

Comment: The title "Convert word doc to rtf" has got nothing to do with iTextSharp nor Pdfs - consider modifying

Comment: @m.edmondson: thanks for correction
@Lazarus: I need iTextSharp because i have use it to convert .rtf to .pdf. Plus it is also free to use :-)

Comment: @Romil - I've edited the question to reflect what you've said here

Comment: Conversion using PDFSharp would also do.

Comment: Excepting some helpful comments..

Comment: iTextSharp is not really free (as in beer) since version 5.0. See http://itextpdf.com/terms-of-use/ for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot.

iText doesn't speak .doc or .docx.  If you were to write a .doc reader, you could use iText to generate a matching PDF, but that wouldn't be trivial either.